# Can't render a simple page when using FatFree and PHP5.3 on Apache 2.2

Tags: php, apache, fat-free-framework

I am using Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.3. I am trying to use Fatfree framework for routing. My index.php file looks like:

```
<?php
require_once 'f3/lib/base.php';

F3::route('GET /','home');
function home() {
    echo F3::render('templates/index.html');
}

F3::route('GET /@pagenum','mainlist');
function mainlist() {
    F3::set('pagenum', @pagenum);
    echo Template::serve('templates/index.html');       
}

F3::run();

?>
```

If I go to "http://localhost:8080/" it correctly renders the file templates/index.html, which means that PHP and Fatfree are working. But If I go to "http://localhost:8080/1" then it doesn't work. I get the following error:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /1 was not found on this server.
```

If I change the first part to

```
F3::route('GET /anotherthing','home');
function home() {
    echo F3::render('templates/index.html');
}
```

then "http://localhost:8080/anotherthing" doesn't work either. It just works on the root. Any help?

**MORE INFO**
This is configured in httpd.conf

```
DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs"
<Directory "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs">
Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from All
</Directory>
```

Modrewrite is enabled:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

And .htaccess looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /fatfree/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /fatfree/index.php [L,QSA]
```

"/fatfree/" base is due to an answer in another SO question that had a similar issue.

I also tried with the following .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite enabled and the rules set (i.e. in a .htaccess file)?

Comment: So where is you index.php? In DocumentRoot/fatfree or in the document root?

Comment: It is in the document root. I added more info to the question.

Comment: If it is in the document root - than you should not need the /fatfree suffix. So you went by the book: http://bcosca.github.com/fatfree/ and  tried the proposed .htaccess and Apache config? Just to make sure: You did restart Apache after editing the httpd.conf (or what it is called in your WAMP server) file?

Comment: Yes. Right now I don't have /fatfree suffix. I am using the proposed Apache and htaccess. I did restart Apache. It looks like a wierd problem because it works for the root (it redirects me) but not for other route.

Comment: `F3::set('pagenum', @pagenum);` doesn't look right. That's going to throw a syntax error. Are the files `index.php` and `.htaccess` in the folder `"C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs"`? They should both be in the same location. Also, if the message `The requested URL /1 was not found on this server.` is not italicized, then the error is coming from Apache, not Fat-Free.

Answer (score 2):

You really need to look at your server logs. If you haven't enabled them, I would suggest you do so. Apache has really good logs. If you see log entries and arent' getting a 500 server error, then it's usually not mod_rewrite.

If you want to be sure the rewrite module is loaded (on Linux), try this:

> [root@server ~]# httpd -M 2>&1|grep rewrite

It will return something to this effect:

> rewrite_module (shared)

Comment: Thanks! I was using wamp and just uncommented mod_rewrite.so in httpd.conf

Answer (score 1):

## Enable rewrite engine and route requests to framework

Try this, this fix works for me.  Modified your .htaccess file just like the code below.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Some servers require you to specify the `RewriteBase` directive
# In such cases, it should be the path (relative to the document root)
# containing this .htaccess file
#
#RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(lib|tmp)\/|\.(ini|php)$ - [R=404]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [END,QSA]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(app|tmp)\/|\.ini$ - [R=404]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is config.ini file in root of fatfree

```
[globals]
DEBUG=3
UI=ui/
```

DEBUG=3 will let f3 show all errors from internal, and changing ui value is important since you need to keep your templates inside ui folder, so in this configuration you've to change it to your own template directory.

As per f3 documentation, static calling convention (F3::xxx) has been deprecated, better option is call an instance of F3 (like $f3->xxx).

Also pleas check HTTPD error logs for isuues related mod_rewrite and .htaccess.

--

Answer (score 0):

You only need that in your index.php

```
$f3=require('lib/base.php');
$f3->config('config/config.ini');
$f3->config('config/routes.ini');
$f3->run();
```

And then in your config.ini :

```
[globals]
DEBUG=3
UI=views/
```

routes.ini :

```
[routes]
GET /=ControllerName->methodThatRenderTheView
GET /@pagenum=ControllerName->methodThatRenderTheView
```

The basic controller to render your view :

```
class ControllerName {
   public function methodThatRenderTheView() {
      $this->f3->set('view', 'template.htm');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same problem as you.

My DocumentRoot in httpd.conf entry look like:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

Using these .htaccess directives:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /fatfree/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /fatfree/index.php [L,QSA]
```

Couple with mod_rewrite are working properly on my end. I have the most recent f3 and wamp as of today.